How nested DLLs fit into VA space?
I'm asking this question in the context of a single virtual address (VA) space in Linux. Let the process in that space link dynamically two libraries, Lib1 and Lib2, that in turn link dynamically Lib3. How will Lib3 fit into the process' VA space: twice, within Lib1 and Lib2 as depicted in (1), or once, alongside Lib1 and Lib2 as depicted in (2)? That is, will Linux guarantee that a given physical address (PA) will never be mapped to two VAs within a single space?
Address space mappings

The library will be present only once - and maybe not at all.
Everything with respect to virtual memory is lazy: pages of libraries are only loaded on demand. If a library really demands another library to be present, virtual memory will be reserved for that library - but that's it. nothing is actually loaded.
If three libraries depend on a fourth library, the space for that fourth library is only present once.
This is easy to check: take a larger application and look at its virtual memory layout in /proc/<pid>/mem. It will only contain libz or libc once.
